# Inverse Mellin transform of the Mellin transform of the binomial PMF

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, binomial-distribution, dirac-delta, mellin-transform

The probability mass function of the Binomial distribution is given by

$$\begin{equation}
f(x)=\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x},
\end{equation}$$
where $p \in [0,1]$ and $x=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ (finite support).

The Mellin transform of $f$ is therefore
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}\{f\}(s)&=\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1} \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{s-1} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.
\end{align}$$
Since $f$ is a probability mass function, the integral becomes a sum. Now I'd like to apply the inverse Mellin transform to get back $f$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}^{-1}\{\mathcal{M}\{f\}\}(x) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s}  \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{s-1} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \right) \mathrm{d}s \\
&=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} k^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align}$$

The problem is that the integral $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} k^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s$ doesn't seem to converge. Essentially it's equal to
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s}k^{s-1} \mathrm{d} s &= \frac{1}{x} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} \left(\frac{k}{x}\right)^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s\\
&=\frac{i}{x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it \ln \left({\frac{k}{x}} \right)} \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}
$$
So the integrand is forever oscillatory, and doesn't seem to have a value. I did read that it "equals" the dirac Delta distribution, but I'm not sure how it'll fit in with the other terms since that's not really a function. But at the same time, since $f$ has support on a finite set, it kind of makes sense for it to show up?

I'm pretty lost, how can I recover $f$?

Comment: I think your question is misguided as you can't evaluate the Mellin transform of a list of integers. It might make more sense to look at the Mellin transform $$\int_0^1 \binom{n}{k}\, p^k\, (1-p)^{n-k}\, p^{s-1} \, dp=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\, \Gamma(n-k+1)\, \Gamma(k+s)}{\Gamma(n+s+1)}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by list of integers? I just meant that f is 0 for all x except for {0, 1, ..., n}, but also "integrates" to 1 on the entire real number line, like a p.m.f does. Essentially you can think of f being defined on the entire real number line, but with some dirac deltas at x = {0, 1, ..., n}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Steven Clark for some clarification. Indeed the dirac-Delta is very relevant here, I should've played around with it more.

What happens is that
\begin{align}
\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s}k^{s-1} \mathrm{d} s &= \frac{1}{x} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i\infty} \left(\frac{k}{x}\right)^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s,\\
&=\frac{i}{x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it \ln \left({\frac{k}{x}} \right)} \mathrm{d}t,\\
&= \frac{2 \pi i}{x} \delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right),\\
&= 2 \pi i \delta \left(k-x\right).
\end{align}

and what I completely missed is that $\mathcal{M}^{-1}\{\mathcal{M}\{f\}\}(x)$ is a function of $x$ on the *real number line*, and that $\delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right) = x \delta \left(k-x\right)$, which not only cancels the $x$ in the denominator that I could not get rid of, but also means that the integral is 0 whenever $x \neq k$. So we get that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}^{-1}\{\mathcal{M}\{f\}\}(x) &=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} k^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s,\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right),\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta\left(k-x\right),\\
&=f(x).
\end{align}
Very cleverly, all the terms inside the sum equal zero except for when $x=k$, which is where the dirac-Delta spikes. This is exactly the behavior $f$ (and probability mass functions in general) would exhibit had it been defined on the entire real number line!

It also does integrate to 1 along $\mathbb{R}$, and the antiderative $\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$ is a step function that changes in value at each $x=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ by $\binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$, which is indeed the binomial CDF.

Comment: $+1$ Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the Mellin transform of

$$f(x)=\binom{n}{x}\, p^x\, (1-p)^{n-x}\tag{1},$$

but rather the Mellin transform of

$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(x)\, \delta (x-k)\tag{2}$$

which, assuming the convention $\int\limits_0^\infty \delta(x)\, dx=1$ (versus $\int\limits_0^\infty \delta(x)\, dx=\frac{1}{2}$ for example), is

$$\mathcal{M}_x[g(x)](s)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\, \delta (x-k)\, x^{s-1} \, dx\right)\\=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)\, k^{s-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\, p^k\, (1-p)^{n-k}\, k^{s-1}\tag{3}$$

and this explains the presence of the Dirac delta terms in the inverse Mellin transform.

---

But you still need to normalize it such that $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, \delta (x-k) \, dx\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\, p^k\, (1-p)^{n-k}=1\tag{4}.$$

---

The remainder of this answer illustrates an alternate perspective on the problem.

---

Assuming the definition

$$f(k)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \binom{n}{k}\, p^k\, (1-p)^{n-k} & 0\leq k\leq n \\
 0 & k>n \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}$$

consider the summatory step function

$$h(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^x f(k)\tag{6}$$

which can be viewed as sort of a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) with first-order derivative

$$h'(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^x f(k)\,\delta(x-k)\tag{7}$$

which can be viewed as sort of a Probability Density Function (PDF).

---

Now consider the Mellin transform

$$H(s)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[h(x)](-s)=s\, \int_0^{\infty} h(x)\, x^{-s-1} \, dx\\=2 \pi\, f(0)\, s\, \delta(-i s)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^s}\tag{8}$$

which is equivalent to the Mellin transform

$$H(s)=\mathcal{M}_x[h'(x)](1-s)=\int_0^{\infty} h'(x)\, x^{-s} \, dx\\=2 \pi\, f(0)\, s\, \delta(-i s)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{f(k)}{k^s}\tag{9}$$

---

The function $h(x)$ is recovered from the inverse Mellin transform

$$h(x)=\mathcal{M}^{-1}_s\left[\frac{H(s)}{s}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\alpha-i \infty}^{\alpha+i \infty} \frac{H(s)}{s}\, x^s \, ds=\sum\limits_{k=0}^x f(k)\tag{10}$$

where $\alpha=0$ must be used for the $2 \pi\, f(0)\, s\, \delta(-i s)$ term of $H(s)$ and $\alpha>0$ must be used for the remaining terms of $H(s)$.

---

Formulas (6) to (10) above are more consistent with the way a summatory step function

$$r(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(k)\tag{11}$$

is related to its corresponding Dirichlet series

$$R(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(k)}{k^s}\tag{12}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Indeed the dirac-Delta is very relevant here, I should've played around with it more.

What happens is that
\begin{align}
\frac{i}{x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it \ln \left({\frac{k}{x}} \right)} \mathrm{d}t
&= \frac{2 \pi i}{x} \delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right).
\end{align}

Comment: What I missed is that $\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)=0$ when $k=x$, so that $\delta(0)=\infty$ exactly when $k=x$. So we get that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}^{-1}\{\mathcal{M}\{f\}\}(x) &=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} k^{s-1} \mathrm{d}s\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{f(x)}{x}.
\end{align}

Almost there, but now there's an extra $x$ in the denominator? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: @Efficiency It appears you're assuming the definition $\delta(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & x \neq 0\\ \infty, & x = 0 \end{cases}$ which is wrong and a common misconception.

One way to define it is

$$g(x)\to\delta(x)$$

if

$$\forall\,f(x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\, f(x)\,dx \to f(0)$$

which is satisfied by distributional limit representations such as

$$\delta(x)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(\int\limits_{-f}^f e^{i 2 \pi x t} \, dt\right)=\underset{f\to\infty}{\text{lim}} \left(2 f\, \text{sinc}(2 \pi f\, x)\right).$$

Comment: @Efficiency I've been wondering if you could consider $$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{x}\, p^x\, (1-p)^{n-x}\, \delta (x-k)$$ as sort of a Probability Density Function (PDF) and $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \, dx=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\, p^k\, (1-p)^{n-k}$$ as sort of a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF).

Comment: Yeah you could consider that as a PDF! It's essentially a generalization of a PMF. The bottom function is definitely a valid CDF.

And I know the delta distribution is not actually $\infty$ at 0. But I'm wondering how I got that extra $\frac{1}{x}$ in that denominator? Or does what you say imply that the integral $i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it \ln \left({\frac{k}{x}} \right)} \mathrm{d}t = 2 \pi i x \delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right)$?

Comment: I suppose it does! See https://mathoverflow.net/a/79925/501810.

Apparently $\delta\left(\ln\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\right) = \delta\left(\ln(k)-\ln(x)\right) = x\delta\left(k-x\right)$. That leads to the $x$ terms being canceled.

I suppose I need to take much more care when dealing with the dirac-delta distribution.

Comment: @Efficiency I didn't explain the CDF/PDF analogy quite right in my comment above, so I updated my question above to clarify it.